# Why does Box2D/Farseer EdgeShape have 4 vertices defined?

Tags: c#, c++, box2d, farseer

When you create a Farseer (or Box2D) edge `Fixture` you write:

```
FixtureFactory.AttachEdge(start, end, bodyToAttachTheFixtureTo);
```

Which makes sense - you need `start` and `end` point to define an edge.

What bothers me is when you want to read the `Fixture`. Assuming `fixture` is the `Fixture` we read:

- `((EdgeShape) fixture.Shape).Vertex1`
- `((EdgeShape) fixture.Shape).Vertex2`

**Should be the only options.** But we also get `Vertex3` and `Vertex4`. Why? What do they mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely vertices 1 and 4 are 'ghost vertices': http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/ghost-vertices

If you're looking for the original two vertices you gave when creating the edge, you probably want vertices 2 and 3.